# Is this true of the Reimann zeta function?

Tags: prime-numbers, riemann-zeta

Do all prime numbers and only prime numbers have this property:

$p$ is a factor of the simplified denominator of $ζ(-p + 2)$?

I was looking at the values of the Reimann-zeta function and noticed this property. I'm not familiar with this function and don't have a background in math, so I was wondering if someone would be able to chime in :).

Comment: Hi, could you tell us some [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/1017316) about your question?

Comment: Sure, although there's not much to say unfortunately. I was looking at the values of the function and noticed this property. I'm not familiar with this function and don't have a background in math, so I was wondering if someone would be able to chime in :)

Comment: The name of the man was Riemann.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $ζ(-n + 2)=\frac{B_{n-1}}{n-1}$ for all $n \ge 2$ (so in particular $\zeta(0)=-1/2$). The [Theorem of Clausen and Von Stadt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Staudt%E2%80%93Clausen_theorem) tells us precisely how the denominator of $B_n$ looks for $n$ even namely

$B_n=-\sum_{p-1|n}\frac{1}{p}+C_n$ where the sum is taken on all primes st $p-1|n$ and $n$ even and at least $2$ while $C_n$ is some integer. Hence for $p$ odd prime we clearly have that $p$ appears in the denominator of $B_{p-1}$ hence of $\zeta(2-p)$ while for $p=2$ the result also holds as noted

Comment: soo interesting! thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help

Comment: What about the composite cases ? The question also asks whether this holds only for the primes.

Comment: @Peter the theorem above give the decomposition of the denominator of $B_n$ and since $(n,n-1)=1$ one can get $n$ to appear in the denominator of $\zeta (2-n)$ iff $n$ is square free and if written as a product $p_1..p_k$ of odd distinct primes, each $p_m-1$ divides $n-1$ which is easily seen to be equivalent to $p_m-1|n/p_m-1$; now from size considerations you need $k \ge 3$ and then you need to find a bunch of odd distinct primes satisfying that $p-1$ divides the product of all the others minus $1$